# Trying to run a webapp at Vercel

Tags: flutter, dart, vercel

Im trying to run a flutter webapp at Vercel, but i receive this error on try to make deploy

> ...
> Target dart2js failed: ProcessException: Process exited abnormally with exit code 1:

> ../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/carousel_slider-4.2.1/lib/carousel_slider.dart:358:33:
> Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'PageStorageBucket' which excludes null.
>
> - 'PageStorageBucket' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/page_storage.dart' ('flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/page_storage.dart').
>   PageStorage.of(storageContext)?.readState(storageContext)
>   ^
>   ../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/wiredash-1.7.4/lib/src/metadata/device_info/device_info_generator.dart:46:32:
>   Error: The getter 'physicalGeometry' isn't defined for the class 'SingletonFlutterWindow'.
> - 'SingletonFlutterWindow' is from 'dart:ui'.
>   physicalGeometry: window.physicalGeometry,
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   Error: Compilation failed.
>   Command: /vercel/path0/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart --disable-dart-dev /vercel/path0/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/snapshots/dart2js.dart.snapshot --platform-binaries=/vercel/path0/flutter/bin/cache/flutter_web_sdk/kernel --invoker=flutter_tool -Ddart.vm.product=true -DFLUTTER_WEB_AUTO_DETECT=true -DFLUTTER_WEB_CANVASKIT_URL=https://www.gstatic.com/flutter-canvaskit/347f506a341fc94b8881eea54a5b8ad90e746ddb/ --native-null-assertions --no-source-maps -o /vercel/path0/.dart_tool/flutter_build/0952ba82452baf4e7b080315bcfcb493/app.dill --packages=.dart_tool/package_config.json --cfe-only /vercel/path0/.dart_tool/flutter_build/0952ba82452baf4e7b080315bcfcb493/main.dart
>   #0      RunResult.throwException (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:127:5)
>   #1      _DefaultProcessUtils.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:280:19)
>   ...
>   Error: Failed to compile application for the Web.
>   Error: Command "flutter/bin/flutter build web --release" exited with 1

I think, the error is in Error: Compilation Failed line.
Running with this configurations in Vercel deploy:

Build command: **flutter/bin/flutter build web --release**
Output Directory: **build/web**
Install Command:
**if cd flutter; then git pull && cd .. ; else git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable; fi && ls && flutter/bin/flutter doctor && flutter/bin/flutter clean && flutter/bin/flutter config --enable-web**

I try with another commands, but, same error.

Comment: I don't know what "Vercel" is without any reference, I assume it's a package. I think it would be help us to understand if you share some code examples on how to reproduce this error.